# React Native iOS Development Build - Local Assets not showing

Tags: ios, react-native

I have been making this iOS app on my Macbook and it works fine, assets are shown without problem, but when I try setting up the code and repo on another MacBook, it builds fine but all the local assets are blank on the simulator screen.

A lot of questions on this, but all answers focus on the release build. I am not trying to build release, I am running `react-native run-ios` to run the app on the simulator, following the exact steps that I used to setup the project on my mac.

Xcode 11.6

My Folder Structure is:

```
App
  |
  |-ios
  |-components
    |-assets
      |-images
        |- image files
    |- [JS files that use the assets]
```

Also if it helps I'm using the assets like this - Image from ReactNative

```
<Image source={require('./assets/images/hero.png')} style={{flex: 1, height: 205, resizeMode: 'contain'}} />
```

Help appreciated!